# What is being used for migrations with martini?

Tags: go, martini

I'm trying to learn martini, coming from Rails. What's being used for database migrations in the martini world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing in martini. It is just a helper for writing web services. If you want database migrations, or a database at all, use third-party packages.

An example tool stack would be:

- [goose](https://bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose) for creating migrations
- [gorp](https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp#quickstart) for a database object layer

This or a completely different setup, e.g. using Go's standard database package, can be used with martini.